# How to copy the bold value and paste in next column continuously until the next bold value find?

Tags: vba

I have a file with scattered data. In column A, customer name, product name and sales date are available. And in column B, sales volumes are available.
I need to impose the sumif formula to check the product-wise total sales volume. To do that, I need to get all the products name just beside the sales volume cell in column B.

Since I have more than 5000 rows of data, I want to have all the product name in column C using macro (beside the sales volume). In Column A, the products name are in bold.

[image]

I am trying to above expected output using VBA. Is there anyway to do that using VBA within a very short time ?

Comment: Is there always a "DEF Costomer" in between? Does "1-Jan" start with a lot of spaces? Could use an excel formula as well if they do start with spaces (assuming we're starting on row 3 with formula): `IF(LEFT(A2,7) = "PRODUCT",A2,IF(LEFT(A3,1) = " ",C2,""))`.
General rule of thumb however: try something out first and show us what you tried ;)
As for checking bold on cell: `If Range(Zell).Font.Bold Then`

Comment: Hi @Notus_Panda i tried with several formula. But unfortunately nothing works here due to so much scattering. Thus i thought vba can work fine. But i have very limited knowledge on that part.

Comment: What about my questions? Coding is a lot about rules, if you don't know the limitations, it can get quite tricky :)

Comment: @Notus_Panda, I have done  it using a formula. Sharing that in the answer.

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at: https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/how-to-copy-the-bold-value-and-paste-in-next-column-continuously-until-the-next/ AND https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-copy-the-bold-value-and-paste-in-next-column-continuously-until-the-next-bold-value-find.50033/

Answer (score -1):

I have made it done using a formula. That is -

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A4),C3,A4)`

Comment: Welp, that would've been handy to know that it's a number. Glad you got your own answer though!